# ERRO NO ANDROID STUDIO APP FECHANDO AO EXECUTAR

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

recentemente (e do nada) surgiu um erro extremamente irritante e chato no Android Studio, na verdade a própria IDE nem erro aponta em nenhum código, mas quando vou executar um app que tenha imagens, como pelo menos um imageView ou Button com um background, ao executar o app ele fecha na hora no celular. 
Eu estou até pegando projetos prontos de pequenos apps do curso que eu faço e só abrindo eles no Android Studio e executando, no caso não tem nenhum erro no código, mas mesmo assim fica fechando. Já troquei a versão da IDE, já instalei de novo do zero, já dei Rebuild e Clean, mas nada resolve.

Vou deixar os códigos abaixo de um app pequeno que possui uma activity com tres botoes, um play, um pause e um stop, o projeto está funcionando de boa, porém ao colocar um imagem de background nos botoes, o app já fecha ao executar. Deixarei também os erros que aparecem no Logcat.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext() , R.raw.musica);


    }





    public void executarSom(View view) {

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }



    public void pausarMusica(View view) {


        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }


    }



    public void pararMusica(View view) {


        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();

            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext() , R.raw.musica);

        }


    }






}
```

activity_main :
(Coloquei um background apenas no botão Pause, para vcs verem, mas quando eu tiro esse background e deixo so o botão igual os outros o app funciona normalmente, mas colocando a imagem de background, não vai)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pause"
        android:onClick="pausarMusica"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:onClick="executarSom"
        android:text="Play"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:onClick="pararMusica"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Aqui está o que aparece no Logcat no momento que o app fecha no celular e fica escrito nele "O MediaPlayer parou" :

```
12-15 00:03:42.280 20121-20121/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:03:42.280 20121-20121/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:03:43.594 20135-20135/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:03:43.594 20135-20135/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:03:44.148 20151-20151/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:03:44.148 20151-20151/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:03:44.342 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:03:44.803 20163-20163/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer, PID: 20163
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer:drawable/pause" (7f060062)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060062 a=-1 r=0x7f060062}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2420)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2360)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:650)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695) 
12-15 00:03:50.004 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=2,01 rxSuccessRate=8,38 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-57
12-15 00:04:20.014 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=0,00 rxSuccessRate=1,06 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-69
12-15 00:04:20.019 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Medeiros"WPA_PSK with 2462
12-15 00:04:20.481 20199-20199/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:20.481 20199-20199/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:21.144 20212-20212/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:21.144 20212-20212/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:21.771 20230-20230/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:21.772 20230-20230/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:24.610 20242-20242/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:24.610 20242-20242/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:25.204 20255-20255/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:25.204 20255-20255/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:28.841 20269-20269/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:28.841 20269-20269/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:29.256 15251-15251/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.b(86): Package name null is not an installed package
12-15 00:04:29.258 15251-15251/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.gi.d(83): PSIC will not run.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided installer data is not valid (uid: -1, package name: null). Data could be missing, invalid, or just not match each other. PSIC will not run.
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.gi.d(SourceFile:58)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageVerificationService.a(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.b.h.onStartCommand(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageVerificationService.onStartCommand(SourceFile:9)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2891)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
12-15 00:04:30.009 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=1,38 rxSuccessRate=2,01 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-69
12-15 00:04:30.010 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Medeiros"WPA_PSK with 2462
12-15 00:04:31.403 1283-1299/? E/DefContainer: OBB dir: /storage/MicroSD/.android_obb/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer not found
12-15 00:04:31.447 3678-3678/? E/PackageActionReceiver: ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
12-15 00:04:31.616 3678-3701/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-15 00:04:32.310 20376-20376/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:32.310 20376-20376/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:32.326 19212-19231/? E/Clock_animationIcon: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
12-15 00:04:32.661 1327-1327/? E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.asus.launcher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.asus.launcher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3336)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
12-15 00:04:32.854 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:04:33.218 20424-20424/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-15 00:04:33.251 20424-20424/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-15 00:04:34.807 3678-3678/? E/PackageActionReceiver: ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
12-15 00:04:35.596 20593-20593/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
12-15 00:04:35.597 20593-20652/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:04:35.607 20593-20655/? E/GoogleTagManager: Invalid macro: _gtm.loadEventEnabled
12-15 00:04:35.725 19212-19231/? E/Clock_animationIcon: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
12-15 00:04:36.160 20663-20663/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.instagram.android
12-15 00:04:36.819 20752-20752/? E/ACRA: Skipping ANR Detector for process: com.instagram.android:videoplayer
12-15 00:04:50.004 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=3,74 rxSuccessRate=3,25 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-65
12-15 00:04:50.004 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Medeiros"WPA_PSK with 2462
12-15 00:04:55.869 20779-20779/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:55.869 20779-20779/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:55.916 667-777/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '245c764a com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-15 00:04:56.066 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:04:56.482 20793-20793/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:56.483 20793-20793/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:57.114 20813-20813/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:57.114 20813-20813/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:58.297 20826-20826/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:58.297 20826-20826/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:58.870 20842-20842/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:04:58.870 20842-20842/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:04:59.043 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:04:59.534 20854-20854/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-15 00:04:59.583 20854-20854/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
12-15 00:05:13.324 1327-1953/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:05:20.011 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=3,51 rxSuccessRate=4,98 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-69
12-15 00:05:29.283 20885-20885/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:29.283 20885-20885/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:29.453 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:05:29.867 20899-20899/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:29.867 20899-20899/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:30.004 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=2,97 rxSuccessRate=4,31 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-66
12-15 00:05:30.004 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Medeiros"WPA_PSK with 2462
12-15 00:05:30.501 20919-20919/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:30.501 20919-20919/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:33.230 20934-20934/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:33.230 20934-20934/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:33.746 20947-20947/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:33.746 20947-20947/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:37.044 20961-20961/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:37.044 20961-20961/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:37.445 15251-15251/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.b(86): Package name null is not an installed package
12-15 00:05:37.447 15251-15251/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.gi.d(83): PSIC will not run.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided installer data is not valid (uid: -1, package name: null). Data could be missing, invalid, or just not match each other. PSIC will not run.
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.gi.d(SourceFile:58)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageVerificationService.a(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.b.h.onStartCommand(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageVerificationService.onStartCommand(SourceFile:9)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2891)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
12-15 00:05:40.244 1283-1299/? E/DefContainer: OBB dir: /storage/MicroSD/.android_obb/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer not found
12-15 00:05:40.343 3678-3678/? E/PackageActionReceiver: ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
12-15 00:05:40.481 3678-3701/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
12-15 00:05:40.967 19212-19231/? E/Clock_animationIcon: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
12-15 00:05:41.117 21027-21027/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-15 00:05:41.117 21027-21027/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-15 00:05:41.429 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
12-15 00:05:41.911 21056-21056/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   ...ompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer:drawable/pause" (7f060062)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060062 a=-1 r=0x7f060062}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2420)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2360)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:650)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
...................
```

61/? E/ACRA: Initializing ANR detector for process: com.instagram.android
    12-15 00:05:50.005 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=7,48 rxSuccessRate=7,36 targetRoamBSSID=30:99:35:a0:1b:ef RSSI=-65
    12-15 00:05:50.005 667-786/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine starting scan for "Medeiros"WPA_PSK with 2462
    12-15 00:06:01.147 1327-1882/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
    12-15 00:06:01.604 21448-21448/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer, PID: 21448
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer/com.example.joaovictor.mediaplayer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button

```
   ................. mais erros... (nao cabe mais aqui)
```

Comment: Boa mano se pretendes mostrar uma imagem em um botão convém usar um imagebutton e defineres o a imagem em atributo src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que testei aqui o problema provavelmente pode ser na pasta "drawable/pause"
Já aconteceu comigo o mesmo erro.

Verifica se não tem nenhuma pasta em res do tipo "drawable-vXX". O que pode tá acontecendo é que esse seu drawable está em apenas em uma pasta referente a versão "vXX"
E ao utilizar uma versão menor acontece o erro.

Pegue essa imagem "pause" e cole em todas pastas que tiver drawable.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Se ajudei marque essa resposta como útil, para ajudar outros desenvolvedores com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Deve ser isso mesmo o problema, obriagdo xD